# Can't find whats wrong with this code (scheme)

Tags: list, scheme, set

I am writing a procedure that runs in linear time that returns any numbers that are not a part of both sets. The current code I have is

```
(define (set-diff setA setB)
    (define (iter A B result)
        (if (or (null? A) (null? B))
            (reverse result)
            (if (>= (car A) (car B))
                (iter (cdr A) (cdr B) '() )
                    (if (<  (car A) (car B))
                    (cons (car B) result (iter (cdr A) (cdr B) '() ))))))
(iter setA  SetB '()))
```

The problem that keeps arising is that when this function is run, say through the arbitrary test case `(set-diff '(1 5 7 9) '(1 7 8 9 10)) ; (5)` , I get an error message saying that I've called the procedure with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: There's something you're not mentioned about the error message.  You said "an error message saying that I've called the procedure with the  wrong number of arguments."  **Which** procedure, though?  I bet the error message says `cons`, since (as both answers so far have pointed out) `cons` is being called with three, when it only takes two.  If you copy and paste your exact error messages into your questions, some of these issues will be much more readily solved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial syntax error (calling a function with the wrong number of arguments) that isn't likely to be useful to other users.


Answer (score 2):

It's not stated in the question, but it looks like the input sets are sorted, and the output set must be sorted, too. If that's the case, then the code in the question is far from correct, you're not considering all the cases, the way the recursion is advancing is incorrect and the way the result is being built is wrong, too.

Also the last `if` doesn't have a corresponding `else` part, which might raise an error in some interpreters (and anyway it'd be a better idea to use a `cond` here), the last `cons` is receiving three arguments instead of the correct two (this is causing the error reported, by the way) and finally the parameters passed to `iter` are different from the parameters received by the procedure (this might or might not be an issue, if the interpreter takes letter case into consideration). The function needs a complete rewrite to work:

```
(define (set-diff setA setB)
  (define (iter A B result)
    (cond ((null? A) (append (reverse result) B))
          ((null? B) (append (reverse result) A))
          ((< (car A) (car B))
           (iter (cdr A) B (cons (car A) result)))
          ((> (car A) (car B))
           (iter A (cdr B) (cons (car B) result)))
          (else (iter (cdr A) (cdr B) result))))
  (iter setA  setB '()))

(set-diff '(1 5 7 9) '(1 7 8 9 10))
=> '(5 8 10) ; this is the correct answer for the sample input
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cons` on the next-to-last line has three arguments, but should only have two.

You also spelled `setB` and `SetB` differently in two places, which may cause problems for some Scheme systems.